# Ajax post does not work after document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make an Ajax call after my document is ready. Here is my code :

```
<script>

        $(window).bind("load", function () {
            getCategories();

        });
    </script>

    <script>
        function getCategories() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCategoryTest", "Category")',
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: "application/json",
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    var categoryList = JSON.parse(result);

                    $.each(categoryList.result, function (i) {
                        $("#menuCategory").append('<li>' + categoryList.result[i].CategoryName + '</li>');


                    });

                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

My ajax post works without using window.bind but I have to run my ajax post after my document is loaded.

Comment: What is your jQuery version?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, I use latest version..  from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Comment: What is your question? What error are you seeing?

Comment: Why are using window.bind event instead of document.ready ?

Comment: `$(function() { getCategories(); })` should work.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: I changed my code with  $(document).ready but the same result My ajax post does not work altough it works without using document.ready

Comment: You link shows `jQuery v1.11.1`. Latest appears to be `v3.1.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    getCategories();
  });

  function getCategories() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCategoryTest", "Category")',
      dataType: "html",
      contentType: "application/json",
      async: false,
      success: function(result) {
        var categoryList = JSON.parse(result);

        $.each(categoryList.result, function(i) {
          $("#menuCategory").append('<li>' + categoryList.result[i].CategoryName + '</li>');


        });

      }
    });
  }
</script>
```